Apache Nifi get all data csv in folder APi's
Apache Nifi: How to get all data csv in folder API.
Example : I have data in http://20.30.06.08/files/test/
and from the API's have a many csv data like :
Name                    lastmodified              size
test-20240625.csv   2024-06-26 08:14      3.9K
test-20240626.csv    2024-06-27 08:14      2.9K
test-20240627.csv    2024-06-28 08:14      1.9K
how to get all data csv from folder test, with apache nifi (invokedHTTP processor) ?
I'm try with invokehttp processor > extract text > routeonattribute > Updateattribute > InvokeHTTP .
and i'm just get one data and first last modifed.
my expecting is get all data from this APi's folder in test http://20.30.06.08/files/test/.
or just get data from the last modified
